# Can't display section elements inline

Tags: css

I have three section elements that hold css animations inside.  When I try to put them side by side using display: inline or float them, they pile up.

HTML

```
<section class="spinner-1">
<div class="spinner"></div>
</section>

<section class="spinner-2">
 <div class="spinner"></div>
</section>

<section class="spinner-4">
 <div class="spinner"></div>
</section>
```

CSS

```
.spinner {
   position: absolute;
}

.spinner-1, .spinner-2, .spinner-4 {
  height: 100px;
  width:  200px;
}
```

you can see the rest of the css code and preview in [codepen](http://codepen.io/codeunshackled/pen/xRxYoa).

Comment: `float` seems to be working, unless i've misunderstood: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GNRBMZ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're setting the `.spinner` itself to `position: absolute`.

You need to use `display: inline-block` because you're expecting them to maintain their own width and height. `display: inline` elements have no direct control over their width and height, so the elements do nothing.

Comment: why the second section positions itself so far away from the first section, given that there's no margin separating both elements?

Comment: Your `.spinner-1` has a width of 200px. Shrink it to 100px and they're even.

Answer (score 2):

```
section {
  float: left;
}
```

Does it in your codepen.

Answer (score 1):

section {display:inline-block;}

They won't stack this way.